# Why does Racket start with a different value for (current-memory-use) here?

Tags: memory, memory-management, racket

Here is a program `prog.rkt` that prints the estimated memory cost of a useless thread in Racket v7.3.

```
#lang racket

(define (make-wasteful-thread)
  (thread (lambda () (let l () (l)))))

(define (estimate-thread-cost)
  (parameterize ([current-custodian (make-custodian)])
    (collect-garbage) ; Removing this line causes every other estimate to change
    (define th (make-wasteful-thread))
    (collect-garbage)
    (define cost (current-memory-use (current-custodian)))
    (kill-thread th)
    (custodian-shutdown-all (current-custodian))
    cost))

(for ([i (in-range 10)])
  (displayln (estimate-thread-cost)))
```

Below is the program output on my system when run using `racket prog.rkt` in the terminal on Arch Linux.

Why is only the first line different?

```
15464
13400
13400
13400
13400
13400
13400
13400
13400
13400
```

Comment: Are you running it a terminal, DrRacket? I get 4800 and 16304 respectively. All values are the same though (macOS).

Comment: @soegaard I actually also tested this on macOs, use 7.0 and create executable and I observe the same. I duplicated `make-wasteful-thread` and did one of each in iteration in hope I would see the 2 first be different, but they aren't, but I also see 3 values but not consistent with which one is run.

Comment: @soegaard In shell on Arch Linux using `racket prog.rkt`. Question edited to add details.

Comment: It seems that compiling with `raco make --disable-inline` on my machine keeps all of the printed values the same.